# Zip entire directory on Amazon S3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I have a directory with small files on S3, is there a way to easily zip up the entire directory and leave the resulting zip file on S3 Using JAVA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355006/download-multiple-files-in-parallel-to-a-zip-file-from-s3-using-java

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 does not have an operation that lets you ZIP up objects in an S3 bucket out of the box. However, you can do this with AWS SDK for Java V2. The high level steps are:

1. Get all objects in an S3 bucket by calling **[s3.listObjects()](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/ListObjects.java)**.
2. For each object, get the byte[] by calling **[s3.getObjectAsBytes()](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectData.java)**.
3. Place each file name and each byte[] into a MAP.

**Map<String, byte[]> mapReport = new HashMap<>();**

4. You can use Java logic to create a ZIP from the MAP.
5. Put the ZIP into an S3 bucket by calling [s3.PutObject](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/PutObject.java).

To create ZIP, use Java logic such as:

```
  // Pass a map and get back a byte[] that represents a ZIP of all images.
    public byte[] listBytesToZip(Map<String, byte[]> mapReporte) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
            for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> reporte : mapReporte.entrySet()) {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(reporte.getKey());
                entry.setSize(reporte.getValue().length);
                zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                zos.write(reporte.getValue());
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
```

I tested these steps from my sample web app. My web app downloaded the ZIP file using the logic specified in this thread. Results were perfect:

[image]